# Adding next and prev buttons to jQuery image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made an image gallery using jQuery (click on the image and it appears big on the screen). 
Hence I wanted to add a 'next' and 'prev' button to switch from view, basically replacing the src attribute from the image highlighter with the next or previous image when clicked. But this doesn't seem to be working.

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/bg-flower-1.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/bg-flower-2.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/bg-flower-3.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/hand-rose55.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ROSE-BLACK.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 test-padding">
            <img src="http://www.truestorytattoo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/rose-blgr.jpg" class="img-padding img-highlight" style="width: 100%;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="photo-size">
            <a href="#" class="close">CLOSE</a>
            <div class="image-viewer"></div>
            <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
            <a href="#" class="prev">PREV</a>
           </div>
```

I'm not even sure if the `next` function is in the right position for overwriting the data:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.img-highlight').click(function () {
        const el = $(".photo-size");
        el.css("display", "block");
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        const block = $(".image-viewer");
        $(this).clone().appendTo(block).attr('src', src).addClass('highlighted-img');
        $('.next').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            var src = $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src');
            alert(src);
        });
    });

    $('.close').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('.image-viewer').empty()
        $(".photo-size").css("display", "none");
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you able to build a simple example that replicates the problem in Codepen, Jsbin etc or StackOverflow snippet tool?
This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/janmoes/pen/YzPxrJz

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  I eventually got the prev and next buttons working.

```
    [https://codepen.io/newschapmj1/pen/WNbZOYy][1]
  $(document).ready(function () {
      //newimg1 - temp copy of img1
      var img1, newimg1;
      const block = $(".image-viewer");

      $('.img-highlight').click(function () {
        const el = $(".photo-size");
        el.css("display", "block");

        //$('div.newgallery').empty();  //empty destination
        img1 = $(this);
        console.log('click img1', img1);

        var src = $(this).attr('src');

        $(this).clone().appendTo(block).attr('src', src).addClass('highlighted-img');
      });

      $('.next').click(function (ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        newimg1 = $(img1).parent().next().children();

        if (newimg1.length > 0) {
          // image found
          $(block.empty());
          $(newimg1).clone().appendTo(block);

          $(block).addClass('highlighted-img');
          img1 = newimg1;
        }
        else {
          //no image - so do nothing
        }

      });

      $('.prev').click(function (ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        newimg1 = $(img1).parent().prev().children();

        if (newimg1.length > 0) {
          // image found
          $(block.empty());
          $(newimg1).clone().appendTo(block);

          $(block).addClass('highlighted-img');
          img1 = newimg1;
        }
        else {
          //no image - so do nothing
        }

      });


      $('.close').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        $(block).removeClass('highlighted-img');
        $(block.empty());

        $(".photo-size").css("display", "none");
        img1 = null;
        newimg1 = null;

      });

    });
```

Comment: It does work untill you click on close and click on an image again, the image highlight block will appear without an image, if you click next or prev, it will show probably the first image of the gallery then. Checked it on the codepen link!

Comment: Well spotted, I took so long to get a working solution I forgot to test it thoroughly. I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it works perfectly. For example if i have 2 `.container` classes and they both have a gallery in it like my example, would that break your code, or will it work as two seperate galleries?

Comment: The easy option is to use 2 pages for 2 galleries and then just change the images.  You might be able to replicate a second gallery under the 1st one by  duplicating most of the code and renaming a few things.   Or would you want to select a gallery from a list and then display only 1 gallery at a time per page?  That would be more of a redesign I think. If you can accept my answer that would be appreciated.

Comment: i made the website for a tattoo artist and he wants to have multiple galleries (per category) on the same page, every gallery div is sepearate by a `<hr />`